# warnings while using pyttsx3, pyPDF2 for making an audio book

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

This is the code I am working on:

```
import pyttsx3
import PyPDF2

with open('TSS.pdf', 'rb') as book:
    full_text = ""
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book)
    audio_reader = pyttsx3.init()
    audio_reader.setProperty("rate", 100)
    for page in range(reader.numPages):
        next_page = reader.getPage(page)
        content = next_page.extractText()
        full_text += content 
    audio_reader.save_to_file(content, "TSS.mp3")
    audio_reader.runAndWait()
```

In the document everything is fine but when I am trying to run it, it is giving me this:

> PdfReadWarning: Superfluous whitespace found in object header b'1474' b'0' [pdf.py:1665]

There are multiple of these but the value after b starts from 12 to 1474...
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

These are only warnings. Not fatal errors.

You have to modify the line 6 in your code and add the "strict" argument to "False":

```
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book, strict=False)
```

Here is your full code with modifications:

```
import pyttsx3
import PyPDF2

with open('TSS.pdf', 'rb') as book:
    full_text = ""
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book, strict=False)
    audio_reader = pyttsx3.init()
    audio_reader.setProperty("rate", 100)
    for page in range(reader.numPages):
        next_page = reader.getPage(page)
        content = next_page.extractText()
        full_text += content 
    audio_reader.save_to_file(content, "TSS.mp3")
    audio_reader.runAndWait()
```

I hope it will be hopefull.
Cheers.